# How to input code in CKeditor with oringinal format

Tags: ckeditor

I will use CKeditor to post some code in it ,but it can't keep the original code format as showed in stackoverflow, for example:

```
  public void Test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"c:\tmp\d.txt", $"a: {i}\n");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

but in ckeditor it will be displayed as below:

public void Test() { for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"c:\tmp\d.txt", $"a: {i}\n"); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); } }

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a dedicated plugin, like [Code Snippet](http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet) for this.

Comment: I used the Code Snippet plus, but when I post it ,it can't work in my html page, it only work in my ckeditor instance

Comment: So it looks like your backend was stripping `pre` or `code` HTML elements. That's where is the issue, not the editor itself.